# How to perform zoom-fade slideshow using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here done partially but its not working fine..
Here is my style sheet

```
<style>
body
{
overflow:hidden;
}
div
{
position:absolute;
top:-330px;
left:-50px;
}
#slideshow img
{
position:absolute;
z-index:8;
}
#slideshow img.active
{
z-index:10;
transition-delay:5s;
transition:all 1s ease;
transform:scale(1.25);
}
#slideshow img.last-active
{
z-index:9;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Body statement

```
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\Aravind.P\Desktop\JQuery\Matt Wiebe_Manhattan Skyline_akRhRQ.jpg" class="active">
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\Aravind.P\Desktop\JQuery\Ray_A New Day_YkFhSGU.jpg">
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\Aravind.P\Desktop\JQuery\Luke Ma_Shinjuku Skyline - Sony A7r_a0dkRw.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is my jquery here i done slideshow by adding class

```
<script>
function slideShow()
{
var $active=$("#slideshow img.active");
var $next=$active.next().length ? $active.next():$("#slideshow          img:first");
$active.addClass("last-active");
$next
.addClass("active");
$active.removeClass("active anim last-active");
}
$(function()
{
setInterval("slideShow()",5000);
});
</script>
```

In that above script i am checking whether is there is next image if not then i pointing to first image

Comment: Please i need a image to zoom out and fade by self,

Comment: Please provide solution by pointing demo's or website because i am new to Jquery.

Comment: Or else please post your code as answer.

Comment: I am using $active for storing a active image object

Answer (score 0):

In order to realize that its the last image you can add a class to it:

```
 $("img:last-child").addClass("last");//give some class to last image
```

And now you can check that if *img* has this class so its the last image:

```
    if ($("img").hasClass("last")) {
     $(img:last-child).removeClass("active");
     $(img:first-child).addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Thats ok fine, Here this slide show not working properly